# No internet despite being able to connect to network / 16.04 LTS / 2008 Black Macbook (Blackbook)

Tags: wireless, internet, 16.04, mac, macbook

I'm trying to breath some life into an old macbook of mine and I thought I'd do that with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32bit. Everything seems to be running fine but I'm unable to connect to the internet via wifi.

I can see the network menu, I can see my wifi and I can even connect to my network. However I can't 'connect' to the internet.

I've had a good look through Ask Ubuntu and Google'd my problem but I can't seem to find a result that works.

I've looked at what wireless card I have, checking the card against the correct driver, making sure all the right drivers are installed but still nothing.

Fortunately I'm still able to connect to the internet via eithernet, so I can still download updates and drivers at least.

Granted I'm very new to Ubuntu I can't figure out what to do. Some help would be very much appreciated.

```
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wls4
   version: 03
   serial: 00:22:41:f9:56:a9
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) ip=192.168.1.107 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
   resources: irq:16 memory:d0500000-d0503fff memory:d0000000-d00fffff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: 88E8058 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: ens5
   version: 13
   serial: 00:22:41:35:3b:91
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.11 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:27 memory:d0400000-d0403fff ioport:5000(size=256) memory:d0420000-d043ffff
```

It's not soft or hard blocked either.

```
rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Extra information, hopefully this can help. If not I can always provide more. Cheers for looking.

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 65536  0
bnep                   20480  2
isight_firmware        16384  0
btusb                  36864  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
wl                   6152192  0
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             479232  29 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
joydev                 20480  0
coretemp               16384  0
applesmc               20480  0
kvm_intel             159744  0
kvm                   471040  1 kvm_intel
appletouch             20480  0
input_polldev          16384  1 applesmc
input_leds             16384  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek    73728  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          36864  3
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
snd_hda_codec         118784  3     snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           61440  4     snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                94208  3 snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
cfg80211              499712  1 wl
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            28672  1 snd_seq_midi
lpc_ich                20480  0
snd_seq                57344  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    69632  16     snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
sbs                    16384  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
sbshc                  16384  1 sbs
shpchp                 32768  0
apple_bl               16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                45056  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
drbg                   28672  1
ansi_cprng             16384  0
xts                    16384  2
gf128mul               16384  1 xts
algif_skcipher         20480  0
af_alg                 16384  1 algif_skcipher
dm_crypt               24576  2
hid_appleir            16384  0
hid_apple              16384  0
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                    98304  4 hid_generic,usbhid,hid_appleir,hid_apple
firewire_ohci          36864  0
i915                 1130496  4
firewire_core          65536  1 firewire_ohci
pata_acpi              16384  0
crc_itu_t              16384  1 firewire_core
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
sky2                   53248  0
drm_kms_helper        131072  1 i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
video                  36864  1 i915
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fjes                   28672  0
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   311296  6 i915,drm_kms_helper
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I feel like a fool. All my wifi problems for broadcom were solved with one command found here

https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/internet#TOC-Broadcom:-install-the-right-driver

That command was

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source && sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

Thanks anyway.